# limit inf of a piecewise-defined function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $V$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 1$ and $f$ a real-valued function defined on $V$. Recall that the limit inf of the function for $x\in V$ is defined as
$$\liminf_{y\to x}f(y)=\lim_{r\to0}\{\inf_{y\in B(x,r)\cap V}f(y)\} $$ where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball of center $x$ and radius $r$.
Now suppose $F$ is a closed subset of $ V$ and let $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x\in F$ and $f(x)=h(x)$ for $x\in V\setminus F$, for two given functions $g$ and $h$. My question is: do we have
$$\liminf_{y\to x}f(y)=\min\{\liminf_{\substack{y\to x\\(x\in F)}} g(y),\liminf_{\substack{y\to x\\(y\in V\setminus F)}}h(y)\} ? $$If not, how to find this limit inf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assertion is true. It is the consequence of:

$$\inf A\cup B=\min\{\inf A, \inf B\}$$

and:

$$\min(a,b)=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$$

which is continuous in both $a$ and $b$